# Where should Entity and DTO conversion happen for external calls?

Tags: spring, dto, resttemplate

I have a Spring REST interface and the controller is making the conversion from DTO to Business Entity objects. The Service layer operates on Business Entity objects. However, If my Business Layer wants to call external REST interfaces, where should that Business Entity to DTO conversion happen? At Business Layer? The DAO object using RestTemplate to make the call? Some other layer? The call sequence would current be like this:

```
business layer -> DAO -> RestTemplate -> RESTful service
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally, in `spring framework` the **conversion** of a Model to DTO and backwards, is done by implementing `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` interface. Thus, getting a reusable converter which can be used either in Facade or DAO or Controller, depending on your needs. Business Layer *should not* be concerned about conversion. From my perspective, using converter in DAO is perfectly fine. :)